# HTML styling | Changing layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need some help with HTML styling.

I have this piece of code:

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5e15d2f246.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="text-align: center; padding-right: 15px; font-size: 13px; margin-top: 25px;">
        <i class="fas fa-lock" style="color: black; margin-right: 7px;"></i>
        SSL secure payment
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center; padding-left: 15px; font-size: 13px; margin-top: 25px;">
        <i class="fas fa-undo" style="color: black; margin-right: 7px;"></i>
        100% money-back guarantee
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to change the layout of the guarantees.

I would like to center align the guarantees in 1 line, like so: https://ibb.co/kqKgX1t

But if there is not enough space for the guarantees to be in 1 line, like on mobile view, I would like to center align the guarantees in 2 lines, like so: https://ibb.co/r7vprZk

Could someone please help me out?

Here's how it looks right now:

Desktop view: https://ibb.co/hCksvMx

Mobile view: https://ibb.co/hWwJk7B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `justify-content: center; flex-wrap: wrap;` to the flex container to center and - if necessary - wrap it.

You also should change the `padding` settings on the flex items to get a better-looking result: To create equal distances you could simple add right *and*  left `padding` or `margin` to *both*  flex-items as shown below.

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5e15d2f246.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div style="text-align: center; padding: 0 15px; font-size: 13px; margin-top: 25px;">
        <i class="fas fa-lock" style="color: black; margin-right: 7px;"></i>
        SSL secure payment
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center; padding: 0 15px; font-size: 13px; margin-top: 25px;">
        <i class="fas fa-undo" style="color: black; margin-right: 7px;"></i>
        100% money-back guarantee
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Johannes. Thank you for your answer, it worked. But the space between the guarantees on mobile view is very big (https://ibb.co/LYCzzsL).  Is there a way to minimise it?

Comment: you can change the `margin-top`  on the flex items, and instead put the margin-top on the flex container. If that's not enough, you can also add a small `line-height` value (like `1.2`) and/or add a small `margin-bottom` value which will be smaller than the default margin.